# Date Picker from Material-UI Framework doesnt work on Mobile?

Tags: user-interface, datepicker, material-design, material-ui

Has someone tried the Material-UI Framework from http://material-ui.com?

Is it normal that the `Date-Picker` doesnt work on Mobile? (Tested on iPhone 4)

http://material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

Comment: no one knows it, no one cares, use foundation or bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

add this before using Date Picker

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: I mean the Demo on the website doesnt work either, when visiting with iPhone